# Putting frame counter in the footer of the [beamer] presentation without a theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer

Could you please help me with the putting numbers of the current frame/page on the slides of my presentation. I don't use any theme (no need for one). I'd like to have the number in footer aligned to the right. This is what my current code looks like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{Author name}
\title{Title of the presentation}
\subtitle{Subtitle of the presentation}
\institute{University name}
\date{October, 2013}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
Some text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item one
        \item two       
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: quick hack: add `\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{\hskip6pt\raisebox{2pt}{\color{black}\insertframenumber}}` in your preamble and the frame number will be printed 6pt to the right of the last navigation symbol. If you don't want the navigation symbols but just the frame number, replace with: `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\hskip6pt\raisebox{2pt}{\color{black}\insertframenumber}}`. You may want to customize the appearance of the frame number according to your tastes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution for only the frame number, add the following to your preamble

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{framenumber}%
      \usebeamerfont{framenumber}\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

for this output on your first slide:

[image: Output]

**NOTE 1** If you don't want the total number just remove `/ \inserttotalframenumber` from the previous code.

**NOTE 2** If you are looking for a more sophisticated footer you can use this code in your preamble (from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136298/31058)):

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{0}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\insertshortauthor~~(\insertshortinstitute)
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{0}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{0}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
      \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

for this output:

[image: Output2]

Comment: fantastic, thank you for the solution. How do you remove the page number on the title page?

Comment: @Spike Use `\thispagestyle{empty}` after the `\begin{frame}` for your title frame. And if you want to start with the second frame numbered as 1 and total number of frame to exclude the title frame just play a little with the counters.

Comment: Great, thanks. By the way, when I want to mention your name at the beginning of the comment, it disappears once it's published. I write @Ludovic. Do you know, what am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: @Spike Nothing wrong here because as you are commenting my answer I'll be notify even without a `@Ludovic` in front of your comment.